# How can I make a TCP Server automatically reconnect to a client? C#

Tags: c#, tcp

Below is my code for the TCP server side. The problem is when the app on client machine closes, the server can't automically try to reconnect every 2 seconds until connected. How can I achieve that?

My idea is after connected to the client, server creates a status thread to send a byte to that client every 30s, if fail ---> terminate connection and retry to connect again. I'm not sure if its gonna work.

```
public static TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
public static int port = 6446;
public static string connectTo = "192.168.0.11";
public static NetworkStream dataStream;


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int retry = 0;

TryingConnect:
    try
    {
        do
        {
            if (retry == 10)
            {
                retry = 0;
                Console.Clear();
            }
            cout("Connecting...");
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(connectTo);
            client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
        } while (client.Connected != true);

        cout("Connected!");
        dataStream = client.GetStream();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Debug: MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        retry++;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        goto TryingConnect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't....that's why it's called a _server_

Answer (score 0):

A server is the communication party which listen for connections from clients. A client is the one which initiates the connection. If you would like to server to recreate a lost connection to the client the server would actually be the client in this case because it initiates a new connection.

Apart from the meaning of the words *client* and *server*: if peer C likes S to connect to it C must be first listen and accept incoming connections, which is not the case for the common client. Even if C would do this the network of C must actually be reachable by S to create a new connection. This is often not the case, i.e if C is located in some local network (typical setup at home, work and often on mobile phone) then C is not reachable by S while C itself could reach S. Therefore S could not make a connection back to C.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Is it possible to check the connection is still alive? If not, thrown a exception to jump to the beginning, create a new TCP client object to connect to a specific IP address?

Comment: @LouisTran: you mean if the client can check if the connection is alive without transmitting application data? Try with [TCP keep alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) or implement some application layer heartbeat.